# Finding tables in Windows sql server management

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm working on a project with a colleague where we use SQL commands to obtain data. Im trying to understand what this command does: `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Vehicles].[db_ddladmin].[View_VehicleReadouts] WHERE ECU='" + ecu + "' AND " + wherestr + " ORDER BY Name";`

I have found two tables in sql server management 2014 which are named Readouts and Vehicles but i can't understand what the command does?

Comment: Your SQL is selected from view not a table.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You can find this in Views folder.

Comment: @Kason, As `View_VehicleReadouts` started with `View` word, can be a `VIEW`, but don't forget, it is a name for object which can be a `TABLE` or a `VIEW.

Comment: Yup, but he found two tables in database only. So I guess it should be a VIEW.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what the code line does? ECU stands for the hardware, for an example EBS which stands for breaks and wherestr is a string containing some numbers which specifies the model number of the brake.

Answer (score 1):

Here you've specified the text of the command using the *CommandText* property.  The command text might be the name of a stored procedure, a table name, or a *SQL* statement as shown in the following code.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "myStoredProcedureName";    //Stored procedure 

cmd.CommandText = "Vehicles"                   //Table name 

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM View_VehicleReadouts "     //SQL statement
```

[sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcIVK.jpg)

Since you are having two tables in your database. This can be a view (you can see this under ‘Views’ folder in the object explorer of your sql management studio).

Answer (score 0):

This command runs a select query against `View_VehicleReadouts` object which might be a table or a view. This object is in `Vehicles` database and in schema `db_ddladmin`. For tables Readouts and Vehicles which you have found twice, they must be having different schemas.
Note: Use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: .. Which `ECU` is `ecu` variable and `wherestr` is something like `  ColumnName = ColumnValue`.

Comment: I'm really new to SQL, What do you mean with parametrization to avoid SQL Injection?

Comment: I mean instead of writing query directly from user input, use parameters. Avoid writing queries like  WHERE ECU='" + ecu + " write where ECU=@ecu. check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx